# Get all $ref values, if any, from a JSON schema

Tags: json, bash, jq, jsonschema

I'm new to jq and json schemas. I'm trying to figure out how to examine a schema and get back all $refs (specifically, their values) in to an array that I can examine in bash. I'm trying to get a list of `$ref`s that are external to the file. Let's say I have a schema like this, how can I get an array of "Apple.schema.json" and "Banaan.schema.json" (or the entire propery would be fine)?

I'm using jq, and I'm struggling with knowing how to get a filter. I can look at properties via `jq '.properties' [file], but beyond that, I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "MySchema.schema.json",
    "version": "1.2.3",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "DEFINED_TYPE": { "type": "string" },
        "Apple": {"$ref": "Apple.schema.json"},
        "Banana": {"$ref": "Banana.schema.json"},
        "Chicken": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Chicken"
        }
        "TIME": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `jq -r '.properties.Banana[]' filename`

Comment: That just gives me the Banan one. How do I generically find anything in `properties` that has a ref? Something like `".properties[] where inner-property-key = "$ref"`

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to read all $ref objects into an array in bash

So to get the list of $ref's

```
jq -r '.properties[] | select(."$ref" != null) | ."$ref"' filename
```

Then to add them to an array, use mapfile

```
mapfile -t array_name < <(jq -r '.properties[] | select(."$ref" != null) | ."$ref"' filename)
```

The -t option in mapfile will strip the trailing delimiter from each line read.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking to do. The first command gets me the results I need. Yes, with that array, I want to now iterate over them in a loop in bash. Thanks!

Comment: To be absolutely sure you're only getting the ."$ref" values: `.properties[] | select(."$ref" != null) | ."$ref"`

Comment: Turns out that the `$ref` I'm looking for may be in another section besides `properties`. Is there a way to just search every section?

Comment: Ended up gong with `jq -r '..|objects|select(has("$ref"))|."$ref"' myfile`

Answer (score 0):

1. One way to be succinct while being sure to retrieve just the values at the `"$ref"` key:

```
jq -r '.properties[] | ."$ref" // empty'
```

2. If your shell does not have `mapfile`, then assuming there are no newlines embedded in the '$ref' values, and that you can ignore leading and trailing spaces, you could use a loop along the lines of:

```
ary=()
while -r read it ; do
    ary+=("$it")
done < <(jq -r '.properties[] | ."$ref" // empty' filename)
```

Of course, if you only need to iterate over the "$ref" values, you might not need the shell array at all ....

Comment: If there are newlines in the $ref values, one thing you can do is `arr=(); while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do arr+=("${line}"); done < <(jq -jc '.properties[] | ."$ref" // empty | . + "\u0000"' filename)` as it's always preferred to use nullbytes as delimiters when possible, and I think some versions of jq have `-0/--nul-output` options, but mine doesn't